# How to get the common row of ManyToMany relationship tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
PERSON
---------------------
ID          NAME
1           ALEX
2           BOB
3           JAMES

PERSON_FRUIT
---------------------
PERSON_ID   FRUIT_ID
1           1
2           1
3           2

FRUIT
---------------------
ID          NAME
1           APPLE
2           ORANGE
```

How can I write a query that check whether multiple person have the same fruit?
I need a query that give me the below results.

- If I pass in ALEX and BOB, it would return the fruit they both have which is APPLE.
- If I pass in ALEX, BOB and JAMES, it would return 0 row because they don't have common fruits.

I have tried to use below query

```
select 
    F.NAME 
from 
    PERSON P1
    join PERSON_FRUIT PF1 on P1.ID = PF1.PERSON_ID
    join PERSON_FRUIT PF2 on PF1.FRUIT_ID = PF2.FRUIT_ID
    join PERSON P2 on PF2.PERSON_ID = P2.ID
    join FRUIT F on F.ID = PF1.FRUIT_ID
where 
    P1.ID = 1 and P2.ID = 2 and P1.ID <> P2.ID;
```

to get the common fruit of ALEX and BOB, but this query is limited to pass in 2 person only.

Comment: Which RDBMS is it? And I guess the other problem (not mentioned) you have is how to pass varying number of person Ids.

Comment: Is this just being done in a single SQL query, or is there another bit of code being used also?

Comment: @vnikhil I'm using postgres, currently I have a method to accept two parameter(person1Id, person2Id), I would like to pass in an array of personIds if I found a better sql query

Comment: @Nerdwood , I'm currently using just single SQL query for 2 person query, I would like to know is it possible to use single SQL for many personIds

Comment: Can 1 person be assigned to many different fruits?

Comment: @Nerdwood, yes, one person can be assigned to many different fruit

Comment: Does my query suit your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this query, you need to specify the people as a list of IDs (in the `WHERE` clause), and you need to specify the total number of person IDs given (in the `HAVING` clause).

```
SELECT F.Name
FROM   person_fruit PF INNER JOIN fruit F ON PF.Fruit_ID = F.ID
WHERE  PF.Person_ID IN (1,2,4)    '<- List of person IDs'
GROUP  BY PF.Fruit_ID
HAVING COUNT(Person_ID) = 3       '<- Total number of person IDs'
```

Comment: Great, glad to help!  :)